# Velocidrone "not a leaderboard track"

Tags: velocidrone

In Velocidrone, the drone racing simulator, after creating a custom track and "Uploading" it, I cannot see my own best time for previous flights. When I press "Leaderboard" button it just says: "Not a leaderboard track".

Is it possible to make my track a "leaderboard track"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Velocidrone distinguishes between *Custom* tracks and *Leaderboard* tracks.

Top 200 speed records for the official *Leaderboard* tracks are recorded by the Velocidrone server and [displayed on its website](https://www.velocidrone.com/leaderboards) as well as in the Leaderboard dialog inside a track.

For the *Custom* tracks, however, the best speeds can be only seen in the Nemesis mode (which is the third game mode, in addition to Multiplayer and Single Player).

Velocidrone's official channel also has videos explaining [leaderboards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYQVmWI9n8w) and [Nemesis mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pJZLi3Vq3s).

One important thing to notice is that for your best times to be uploaded to the server and displayed on the Leaderboards you have to press the upload button after completing a race or toggle *Auto Leaderboard Time Upload* to Yes in the Main Settings.